# Is there a shorthand syntax for ext in gradle files?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, syntax

Consider the following line in a dependencies gradle file:

```
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-rt', version: '2.2.10', ext: 'pom'
```

I would like to translate it into the following shorthand instead:

```
compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.10'   ext: 'pom'
```

However, this does not work because of the `ext` section.

**What is the correct syntax to add that part in the shorthand?**

Comment: Aren't you looking for `implementation(enforcedPlatform("tld.domain:group:1.2.3))`? By the way, `compile` is deprecated ;)

Comment: @x80486 I'm working with a legacy file that hasn't yet been upgraded to `implementation`. I'm trying to figure out how to replicate the effect of `ext: pom` in shorthand.

Comment: The column is a little wide, so you may have missed the `ext` part in the first line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
compile com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.10@pom
```

See the [related section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:resolve_specific_artifacts_from_dependency) of the Users Guide.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if this syntax is documented anywhere?

Comment: I suggest looking at the Gradle docs for the version you are using.

Comment: I did that and couldn't find `ext` at all, which is why I asked the question initially. :P

Comment: I just updated my answer with a link to the UG section.